# Проблема при создания проекта unity

Tags: unity3d

У меня проблема при создания проекта в unity 5+

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отправляю ошибку дальше окно закрывается и тишина.

Comment: При каждом запуске крашится?

Comment: да при каждом.,

Comment: Возможно проблема с самим Юнити. Лучше в сапорт им написать =/

Comment: 1. Проверь чтобы в пути установки Unity не было русского языка и различных символов типо точек запятых. 2. Попробуй скачать дефолтный проект и открыть его. 3. Переустанови Unity

Comment: Попробуй переустановить Unity.

Comment: Можно еще другую версию поставить. У меня с многими версиями так было

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите использовать Unity 5, то скачайте последнюю версию Unity 5 она стабильна.

Скачать можно посылке: https://unity3d.com/ru/get-unity/download/archive